# Any ETL/modeling tool to create a ROLAP star schema data warehouse?

Tags: ssas, etl, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, cognos-tm1

I was wondering if there's any software/tool out there which allows one to design/model a cube and have the software generate the code (at least the framework) necessary for updating dimensions and facts in a relational database?

Sorry if this is a dumb question. But, we have tools like Cognos TM1 which I can design a cube and associated ETL processes to bring data in and store in the TM1 cubes. However, I'm looking for something similar to store/maintain the data in the ROLAP star schema database.

Thanks!

Comment: I have used E/R studio for the modeling, but I prefer to hand work my cube code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Turbo Integrator to maintain the cube/dimension structure. See [http://www.bedrocktm1.org/](http://www.bedrocktm1.org) for some help regarding loading and extracting data with TI processes and chores.

I haved used [Cubeware Importer](http://us.cubeware.com/products/cubeware-importer.html) and SSIS as ETL tool in the past to load and save the parent child of TM1 projects. Everything from and to relational databases/SAP BW/flatfiles will work to store dimension tables and cube meta data.